# Reclone mercurial subrepo

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

This seems like it should be really easy, but I can't find anything that directly addresses it in my searching. I have a mercurial repo with subrepos, I have deleted one of the subrepos (the whole folder). How do I reclone that subrepo now? I could do it manually but surely there's a hg command that does the job?

Comment: can you simply update your main repo?

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't pull down a new copy of the subrepo. A stat -S will show that it doesn't exist though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Clean** parameter in your `hg update` to make it pull the subrepo again.

```
hg update -C
```

**Beware** that clean will discard any uncommitted changes in your working directory, so shelve or commit anything you want to keep before doing it.